# Obtener el objeto de una llave foranea en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo estos modelos:

```
class Direccion(models.Model):
    pais = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    calle = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    colonia = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    numero_interior = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    numero_exterior = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    codigo_postal = models.IntegerField()
    datos_adicionales = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)


class Empleado(models.Model): 
    direccion = models.ForeignKey(Direccion, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    activo = models.IntegerField(default=1, editable=False)
```

Y llamo dentro de una tabla en mi template todos los atributos del modelo `Empleado`, pero dentro de una celda quiero llamar todos los atributos de la direccion que le corresponda a cada empleado y concatenarlos, ya estuve buscando como hacerlo pero no encuentro algo aproximado a lo que quiero hacer.

Por ahora solo estoy retornando los valores del modelo `Empleado` y la ID de la dirección así:

```
class EmpleadosList(ListView):
    model = Empleado

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Empleado.objects.filter(activo=1).order_by('id')
        return queryset
```

Y en el template:

```
{% for empleado in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ empleado.id }}</td>
        <td> {{ empleado.nombre }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.apellido_paterno }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.apellido_materno }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.fecha_nacimiento|date:"Y-m-d" }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.curp }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.rfc }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.direccion_id }}</td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es posible llamar dentro de tu template las direcciones relacionadas al empleado:

```
{% for empleado in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ empleado.id }}</td>
        <td> {{ empleado.nombre }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.apellido_paterno }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.apellido_materno }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.fecha_nacimiento|date:"Y-m-d" }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.curp }} </td>
        <td> {{ empleado.rfc }} </td>
        {% for direccion in empleado.direccion_set.all %}
            <td>{{ direccion.pais }}</td>
            <td>{{ direccion.estado }}</td>
            <td>...</td>
        {% empty %}
            <td>!El empleado no tiene direcciones!</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Aunque te recomiendo que uses [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) para obtener las direcciones relacionadas en un solo bloque.

También, tengo algunas recomendaciones sobre tus modelos:

- El campo `activo` de tu modelo `Empleado`, debería ser de tipo [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField), no tiene sentido que uses un entero para representar un valor booleano:

  ```
  activo = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False)
  ```
- En el caso de que un empleado tengo solo una dirección, deberías usar una relación [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

  ```
  direccion = models.OneToOneField(Direccion, null=True, blank=True)
  ```

Comment: Gracias Cesar, lo del campo activo lo tengo así porque realizo un borrado lógico de los empleados y para evitarme convertir de booleano a entero :) .Lo de la relación hasta ahorita lo tengo así porque se planea implementar un histórico de direcciones para cada empleado, y tu respuesta me ayudó, no lo había intentadoxD solo llevo 4 dias con django :c

Comment: @AngieAlejo entiendo! Tranquila, la práctica hace al maestro (o a la maestra) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es obtener el objeto y despues recien filtrar, nose si me exprese bien, lo hice en la versión Django 4.0

```
# models.py

class Servicio(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ServicioActivo(models.Model):  
   servicio = models.ForeignKey(Servicio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# views.py

def resumen(request):    
    serv_web = ServicioActivo.objects.filter(servicio=Servicio.objects.get(nombre="prueba"))    
    return render(request, 'resumen.html', {'serv_webs': serv_web})

# resumen.html

{% for serv_web in serv_webs %}
    {{ serv_web.servicio }}
{% endfor %}
```